# Which ApplicationContext implementation used in simple spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've learned:

> The three commonly used implementation of 'Application Context' are −
>
> `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` − This container loads the definitions
> of the beans from an XML file. Here you need to provide the full path
> of the XML bean configuration file to the constructor.
>
> `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` − This container loads the definitions
> of the beans from an XML file. Here you do not need to provide the
> full path of the XML file but you need to set CLASSPATH properly
> because this container will look bean configuration XML file in
> CLASSPATH.
>
> `WebXmlApplicationContext` − This container loads the XML file with
> definitions of all beans from within a web application.

So how about Spring Boot? I've read some articles, how to get ApplicationContext:

```
> public class A implements ApplicationContextAware {
> 
>     private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
> 
>     @Override
>     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
>         this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
>     }
> 
> }
```

But which exactly implementation of Application Context is used in Spring Boot?

Comment: Try to print the class name of `applicationContext` ?

Comment: Sure, I will do this and answer my question once I ensure myself nobody here knows it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry point of a Spring Boot application is a [`SpringApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html) object. You can choose which implementation to use through its [`setApplicationContextClass(Class)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#setApplicationContextClass-java.lang.Class-) method. Its javadoc states

> Sets the type of Spring `ApplicationContext` that will be created. If
>   not specified defaults to `DEFAULT_SERVLET_WEB_CONTEXT_CLASS` for web
>   based applications or `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` for non web
>   based applications.

which lists the [defaults](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L172) if you don't use that method, ie.

```
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
```

for web based applications and

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
```

for non web based applications.

There's also a [default for reactive web environments](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L179).

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot creates a new type of `ApplicationContext` called `WebServerApplicationContext` which integrates with the embedded server. It further divides into two implementation categories , one for the Servlet Stack ([ServletWebServerApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-application-context)) and other is for the Webflux reactive stack (`ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext`).

The noticeable differences of this new context is that it will create and manage the  embedded server during bootstrapping the context. So you can see this context will return a `WebServer` which has the following interface.

```
public interface WebServer {
    void start() throws WebServerException;
    void stop() throws WebServerException;
    int getPort();
}
```

The `WebServer` can be a `JettyWebServer` ,`NettyWebServer` ,`TomcatWebServer`, `UndertowWebServer` or etc depending of which embedded server are found in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your classpath, for example if you are creating a web application it will probably be an [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html)

Get you ApplicationContext and apply the method getClass() on it to check wich implmentation it is.